Existence of polynomial with the same number of roots on every line
Let $P(x,y)\colon \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a polynomial and let $n =\text{deg } P$.
Qestion. Is it possible that for every nonconstant linear function $l(x,y)$ we have $\# M_l = n$, where
$$
M_l = \{(x,y)\colon \;l(x,y) = 0,\;\;P(x,y) = 0\}?
$$
Equivalent question. Is it possible that for every $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$, polynomial $P(x_0,y)$ has exactly $n$ distinct roots and for every linear function $l(x)$ polynomial $Q_l(x) = P(x, l(x))$ has exactly $n$ distinct roots?
Related question. What happens when we always want to have $n$ roots with multiplicity?
Thoughts. When $n = 1$ this cannot hold because $M_l$ is infinite when $l = P$ and empty when $P = l + C$ with $C\neq 0$. When $n = 2$ the set $\{P(x,y)= 0\}$ is a conic section and for every conic section there is a line which intersects it in less then two different points.
If $\{P(x,y)= 0\}$ is a union of some nice curves one can try and take $l$ to be a tangent to one of these curves, which will produce a multiple root of $Q_l$ resulting in a smaller number in $M_l$. However, I am not able to finish this argument.

Forget polynomials, forget the smooth and nice things; is there such set on a plane at all?

I mean, not based on Zorn's lemma or such.

@IvanNeretin, oh well, I do not know actually.  I was thinking about the topological properties of the curves, however wasn't able to prove or disprove the existence of such nice set in general. Is the existence clear from the  Zorn's lemma point of view?

I don't know either. My mentioning of Zorn's lemma was based on a vague feeling, rather than a rigorous understanding.
